# Reading and Writing External Storage file From Background Not Working Android

Tags: java, android

In my App I am using FirebaseMessagingService under which I am receiving the notification, For these notifications I am creating a log in the external storage, When My app is in running mode, The logs are getting created perfectly, but after the app has been killed, the logs are not getting created, but the notification are coming. I don't understand what's the problem, In logcat also am not getting any exception.

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public String message = null;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

message=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();


if(message.contains("Text")){
        try {
            intent1 = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("TextData", message);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT );
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

            try {

                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("MyStorage"),strNotificationFileName);
                if (file.exists())
                {
                    IsFileExist=true;
                    strNotificationFileName=file.getPath();
                }
                else
                {

                    IsFileExist=true;
                    try{
                        file.createNewFile();
                        strNotificationFileName=file.getPath();
                    }catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            try {
                ArrayList<Object> listNotificationread=readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            UpdateNotificationList("Text");

        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Object> readObject() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("MyStorage"),"Notification.xml");
    if (file.exists()) {

    }
    listNotification = new ArrayList();
    //Create new FileInputStream object to read file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    //Create new ObjectInputStream object to read object from file
    ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    try {
        while (fis.available() != -1) {
            //Read object from file
            NotificationSavedList acc = (NotificationSavedList) obj.readObject();
            listNotification.add(acc);
        }
    } catch (EOFException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    //Collections.reverse(listNotification);
    return listNotification;
}


public void writeObject(ArrayList<Object> listNotification) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("MyStorage"),"Notification.xml");

    //Create FileOutputStream to write file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    //Create ObjectOutputStream to write object
    ObjectOutputStream objOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    //Write object to file
    for (Object obj : listNotification) {
        objOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
        objOutputStream.reset();
    }
    objOutputStream.close();



}

public void UpdateNotificationList(String type) {

    try {

        try {
            if (listNotification.size() > 20) {
                listNotification.remove(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String parsedDate = formatter.format(currentTime);

        NotificationSavedList _NotificationSavedList = new NotificationSavedList(listNotification.size()+1, type, message, parsedDate);
        listNotification.add(_NotificationSavedList);

        writeObject(listNotification);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your code also.

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: see I have added the code @SRBbans

Comment: i thnk this `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` could be the issue.. or try to use NEW_TASK flag.

Comment: @SRBbans as you are saying that's related to notification, my concern is about reading and writing the file.